# Summing a column based off another column that has duplicate values

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple select query in my .NET application that is returning data from an SQL Server Database. Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT Invoice,
       Amount
FROM MyTransaction
```

I need to sum the **Amount** column when the **Invoice** column has more than 1 of the same values.

For instance. If the result of the select query was:

```
    2Z-3451 11245.83
    2Z-3451 9.643
    2Z-3526 71.04
    2Z-3526 0.334
    2Z-3526 8710.8501
    2Z-3566 8687.273
```

I would like to get the sum of 2z-3451 and 2z-3526. 2z-3566 would simply have the amount of 8687.273

This is the result:

```
Invoice   Amount      Total
2Z-3451   11245.83  
2Z-3451   9.643       11255.743
2Z-3526   71.04
2Z-3526   0.334
2Z-3526   8710.8501   8782,2241
2Z-3566   8687.273    8687.273
```

Comment: So what are you expected results here, as it's a little unclear.

Comment: But the sum of a single value is simply that single value. Do you need anything more complicated than `SUM(Amount) FROM MyTransaction GROUP BY Invoice`?

Answer (score 1):

As you write in the comments that you want to also show other columns, without having affect on the group by, I assume you want to join this table to another that has more information about each invoice.
In that case you can use min or max to include these columns so you don't have to include them in the group by, this only works off course if that other table has only one row per invoice

Look at this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4a840a7e4e33249c0db8913b00a2de66) for an example

```
select t.invoice,
       sum(t.amount) as total,
       min(t.otherfield) as otherfield,
       min(i.something) as something
from   MyTransaction t
  left join Invoice i on t.invoice = i.invoice
group by t.invoice
```

Another option is to not group by, but get your total by an `apply`

```
select tr.invoice,
       tr.otherfield,
       tr.amount,
       t.total
from   MyTransaction tr
  outer apply (select sum(mt.amount) total from MyTransaction mt where mt.invoice = tr.invoice) as t
```

See also the DBFiddle

Comment: I simply want to include the other fields in the same table while performing the SUM.

Comment: @JohnO'Neil Check the DBFiddle in my example, it shows other columns from the same table, as from another table. See if you can use that

Comment: @JohnO'Neil Maybe you are better of by not using a group by, see the second query in my answer, or the DBFiddle for the full query

Comment: Thank you. That is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate functions. `SUM` is the one you want here:

```
SELECT Invoice,
       SUM(Amount)
FROM MyTransaction
GROUP BY Invoice
```

Comment: My Aggregate function returns exactly what I want, but I need to be able to include other fields. When I add the other fields, I have to add the other fields in the GROUP BY. This causes the results to not what I need.

Comment: Then edit your question, and include the other columns in both your sample data and your expected result

Comment: And also show the function you have, and tell us what is missing

Comment: This is returning what I want: 
SELECT Invoice,  SUM(Amount) AS TOTAL
FROM AudioConfTransaction

group by invoice. But I need to add other columns in this Function

Comment: What other columns ? We don't see them in your question

Comment: THere are several other fields in the MyTransaction table I want to have returned. One of them is Description. But if I add Description as one of the fields in the SELECT, I have to add that to the GROUP BY which screws everyting up

Comment: If you want help from us, than please edit your question and show us these other columns, and also show them in your expected result. How can we help you if we don't know exact your problem